# Why does convergence in $\mathbb{Q}$ assume the existence of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

One of the "problems" with the rational numbers is that they are not Cauchy complete: if $\{x_k\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$, it does not nessecarily converge in $\mathbb{Q}$. The real numbers do not have this problem: if $\{x_k\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, it nessecarily converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

However, the definition of a convergent $\{x_k\}$ sequence of rational numbers already assumes the existence of $\mathbb{R}$:

$\{x_k\}$ is convergent in $\mathbb{Q}$ iff: $\exists l \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ $\exists N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall k \ge N_0$, $|x_k-l|<\epsilon$

---

Isn't this a bit circular? If we view Cauchy completeness as a motivation for constructing $\mathbb{R}$ (so that we can do analysis, etc), it seems weird that the Cauchy incompleteness of $\mathbb{Q}$ only make sense if we have already defined $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: you could just restrict $\epsilon$ to the positive rationals without making any difference

Comment: No, it's not circular, since when you write "converges" of some sequence is because you *already* have some topology on the set of the *real* numbers, so we **must** have first $\;\Bbb R\;$ to talk of convergence, at least from the point of view you took. One can take **only the rationals** $\;\Bbb Q\;$ and define there toplogy and etc., and then using some abstract algebra form a ring and a maximal ideal and then from here *construct* the real numbers, but I don't think this is what you're dealing with here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody says you have to involve $\mathbb R$ in this definition. In fact it will work just as well (and be satisfied for exactly the same sequences) if you quantify over $\varepsilon$ picked from $\mathbb Q^+$ instead of $\mathbb R^+$ -- or even if you consider only $\varepsilon$ of the form $1/n$ for some $n\in\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Well my next question would be why isn't this the standard why convergence in $Q$ is defined.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou: In my experience it _is_ the standard. Whatever text you quote your definition from must be either confusedly written or following a strange path where presenting a coherent motivation for the reals is not really important to the author.

Comment: Well if that's the case, everything makes sense now. Thanks.